# macOS Kext with valid signature rejected after 2nd installation (high sierra)

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra, kernel-extension

In a machine where my product was installed before, a second installation fails, due to kext signature rejection.

I have seen in some places the same error, for example here: https://support.eset.com/kb6570, however even after clearing the kext_policy table in recovery mode, and approving the kext manually in settings --> security in the next boot, the kext still appears to be unapproved.

For example, running kextutil provides the following:

```
Kalyan:~ KalyanPentakota$ sudo kextutil /Library/Extensions/mycompanyAT.kext/
Password:
Kext rejected due to insecure location: <OSKext 0x7f8e9ff02e20 [0x7fffa11c8af0]> { URL = "file:///Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/mycompanyAT.kext/", ID = "com.mycompany.at" }
Kext rejected due to insecure location: <OSKext 0x7f8e9ff02e20 [0x7fffa11c8af0]> { URL = "file:///Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/mycompanyAT.kext/", ID = "com.mycompany.at" }
Diagnostics for /Library/Extensions/mycompanyAT.kext:
```

kext approval status in database:

```
sqlite> select * from kext_policy;
XE2XNRRXZ5|jp.co.canon.bj.print.BJUSBLoad|1|Canon Inc.|8
KBVSJ83SS9|com.citrix.kext.gusb|1|Citrix Systems, Inc.|8
MK9BR98H51|com.mycompany.at|1|My Company Ltd|1
```

Kext certificate validation:

```
Kalyan:~ KalyanPentakota$ codesign -dvv /Library/Extensions/mycompanyAT.kext/
Executable=/Library/Extensions/mycompanyAT.kext/Contents/MacOS/mycompanyAT
Identifier=com.mycompany.at
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=8179 flags=0x0(none) hashes=250+3 location=embedded
Signature size=4651
Authority=Developer ID Application: My Company Ltd (MK9BR98H51)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Jun 5, 2018 at 6:05:21 AM
Info.plist entries=22
TeamIdentifier=MK9BR98H51
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=1
Internal requirements count=1 size=212
```

I have also tried removing */Library/StagedExtensions/Library/*, but it didn't change anything as well.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to 10.13's kext authorisation, but I've run into code signing issues [when copying signed executables in-place with `cp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40705362/48660). How are you installing the kext? If it's via a pkg, that shouldn't be the problem, if you're using a custom mechanism, consider whether something like this could be tripping up the kext auth system.

Comment: Another question: are other kexts signed with the same certificate approved?

Comment: hi, all the kexts are signed with the same certificate, and the product is built with standard pkg file

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I haven't seen this exact error before. The kext authorisation "feature" certainly has given us quite a lot of trouble as well, with spurious unreproducible failures. As you seem to have a reproducible case on a machine you control, I'd recommend filing a Radar and a DTS incident with Apple unless someone who's solved the same problem shows up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This workaround currently resolved all the cases we encountered in production:

**You should load in recovery mode, disable sip, restart, invalidate kext cache, restart in recovery again and then re-enable sip.**

Detailed steps:

1. From the Apple menu  select Restart.
2. As your Mac restarts, press and hold down the Command(⌘) + R keys immediately upon hearing the startup chime. Hold the keys until the Apple logo appears to get the computer in Recovery mode.
3. The computer is now in Recovery mode. From the Apple menu select Utilities -> Terminal
4. Run the command:
   *csrutil disable*
5. From the Apple menu, select Restart.
6. After the macOS is loaded, open terminal and type:
   *sudo kextcache -invalidate /*
7. if you your kext is located in non standard location, add the custom kext path, for example:
   *sudo kextcache -invalidate /Library/MyApp/MyApp.kext*
8. From the Apple menu, select Restart.
9. As your Mac restarts, press and hold down the Command(⌘) + R keys
   immediately upon hearing the startup chime. Hold the keys until the
   Apple logo appears to get the computer in Recovery mode.
10. The computer is now in Recovery mode. From the Apple menu select
    Utilities -> Terminal
11. Run the command: *csrutil enable*
12. From the Apple menu, select Restart.
13. Now your kext should run..

Comment: what's the kext status in the db?

Comment: I was having problems loading a Logitech Yeti Blue X driver. The procedure above worked like a champ. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.

The flag of /Library/StagedExtensions must be "restricted":

```
ls -laO /Library/StagedExtensions/
```

**drwxr-xr-x@   4 root  wheel  restricted  128 Nov 15  2017 StagedExtensions**

If not, try below cmd from recovery mode:

```
chflags -R restricted /V*/*/Library/StagedExtensions
```

Reboot and try installing the kext.

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to figure that out but it worked. I was unable to set the restricted flag in recovery mode because of a Volume lock from my company. However, I managed to set the flag by 

1) Disable SIP  <- in recovery
2) Set the Restricted Flags <- in normal mode
3) Enable SIP  <- in recovery

Comment: This worked for me after mounting the system drive with Disk Utility.

Answer (score 4):

## Update

**At least one possible cause of that issue is now exactly known, see update Update (2020-04-10) below**

---

`Kext rejected due to insecure location` is no signature rejection IMHO. Where does it say anything about signature? When the signature is the problem, it literary says so. To me that message says the location is insecure.

Have you checked the access permissions of `/Library/Extensions`? If the permissions are too open, the system will refuse to load kernel extensions with `kextload` or `kextutil`. The folder `/Library/Extension` must be owned by `root:wheel` and nobody but `root` must be able to write to that folder.

Same holds true for the access permissions of extensions, which are bundles (`.kext`) and thus actually directories. They must be owned by `root:wheel` and only `root` may have write permission to them.

If you look at the source code of macOS (yes, macOS is widely OpenSource, people tend to forget that), you see that this error is thrown in just one place:

```c
if (authOptions->requireSecureLocation) {
    if (!kextIsInSecureLocation(theKext)) {
        OSKextLogCFString(NULL,
                          kOSKextLogErrorLevel | kOSKextLogValidationFlag,
                          CFSTR("Kext rejected due to insecure location: %@"),
                          theKext);
        result = false;
        goto finish;
    }
}
```

Now `kextIsInSecureLocation()` is very simple:

```c
Boolean
kextIsInSecureLocation(OSKextRef theKext)
{
    NSURL *url = (__bridge NSURL *)OSKextGetURL(theKext);
    if (!url) {
        return false;
    }
    return pathIsSecure(url.path);
}
```

And so is `pathIsSecure()`:

```c
Boolean
pathIsSecure(NSString *path) {
    Boolean is_secure = false;
    BOOL is_protected_volume = rootless_protected_volume(path.UTF8String) ? YES : NO;
    BOOL is_trusted_path = rootless_check_trusted_class(path.UTF8String, "KernelExtensionManagement") == 0 ? YES : NO;

    if (isSIPDisabled()) {
        // SIP is disabled so everything is considered secure.
        is_secure = true;
    } else if (!is_protected_volume) {
        // SIP is enabled and the volume is not protected, so it's insecure.
        is_secure = false;
    } else {
        // SIP is enabled and it is a protected volume, so it's only secure if it's trusted.
        is_secure = is_trusted_path;
    }
    return is_secure;
}
```

So with SIP disabled, any path is secure, with SIP enabled, volumes w/o SIP support are never secure, otherwise there seems to be a list of trusted paths and I know for sure that `/Library/Extensions` is such a trusted path, yet only if its permission are set correctly.

To check if your volume supports SIP, open `Disk Utility` app, select your boot volume and hit `CMD+I`. A window opens that lists all kind of properties and among these should be one saying:

```
System Integrity Protection supported : Yes
```

If it says no, you definitely would have a problem, but I have no idea which one as no way to en-/disable SIP for individual volumes is known, I only imagine that certain file systems or volumes mounted over the network may not be able to support SIP.

### Update (2018-07-31)

Contacting Apple about this, they gave me the following tip:

> Also, in case it is useful, `sudo kextcache --clear-staging` 
>   allows a user to clear the `/Library/StagedExtensions` folder 
>   without booting into recovery.

Not sure if this solves the problem in similar cases, just sharing this information with you here.

### Update (2020-04-10)

Apparently the output of `ls -alO@u /Library/Extensions` should look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root wheel restricted 160 Oct 24 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root wheel restricted 96 Mar 25 13:00 ..
com.apple.rootless 25
drwxr-xr-x 15 root wheel restricted 480 Oct 24 12:18 Extensions
```

Yet on some affected systems it looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root wheel - 128 Apr 6 18:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root wheel - 96 Apr 6 18:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x 13 root wheel - 416 Apr 6 18:57 Extensions
```

As you can see, the `com.apple.rootless` file attribute is missing and the folders are not marked `restricted`. **Please note, that this is the output of a system that does have SIP enabled and where the user has never disabled it himself.**

Unfortunately restoring that attribute is impossible. The value of that attribute is:

```
# xattr -p com.apple.rootless /Library/StagedExtensions
KernelExtensionManagement
```

But even with disabled SIP, the following command will fails:

```
sudo xattr -w com.apple.rootless KernelExtensionManagement \
    /Library/StagedExtensions
```

It returns `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted`. So if one of the work around tricks don't work that others have been posting here (and for some people none of them works!), be prepared to re-setup your system as it's seriously broken and that isn't your fault but Apple is not providing any help here.

Comment: hey @Mecki thanks for the reply, the ownership is valid for all directories in /Library/Extensions (root:wheel)

Comment: @IdoT See updated information, maybe your volume cannot support SIP for some reason. There is no other known reason, not unless I have access to the source code of `rootless_check_trusted_class()`

Comment: thanks again, after disabling SIP, as expected, the drivers loaded, and then reenabling them, causes them to not be loaded again. What my parter found was that if you install them, disable SIP, then invalidate kext cache, and then reenable SIP, the drivers were loaded correctly, thus I suspect it's rather a caching issue, not a volume support for SIP, anyway there's an open bug for apple, I'll update here once I'll get response.

Comment: @Idot what is the model of your computer? Seeing similar situation with multiple users.

Comment: @kainjow it happened on different models and os versions, it appears as a bug in kext cache, try install, reset kext cache, reboot and check if loaded